# JUnit testing a method that returns Flux<String>

Tags: java, mockito, flux

The method in the service layer that is being tested below...:

```
@Service 
public class Service{

public Flux<String> methodBeingTested ()  {

Flux<String> fluxOfTypeString = Flux.just("test");

return fluxOfTypeString;
}
}
```

The JUnit Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
Service service;

@Mock
Utility Util;     
      
 @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

   @Test
    public void test() {

        Flux<String> fluxOfTypeString = Flux.just("test"); 

       when(service.methodToTest()).thenReturn(fluxOfTypeString);
}
```

In Debug mode I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
FluxJust cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
```

And when not in debug mode I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Any ideas on what a possible workaround for this is? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pls add all test class to see how mocks are configured

Comment: I have added all test class. Thanks

Comment: ok, you have `when(service.methodToTest()).thenReturn(fluxOfTypeString);`, since `service` is not a mock, but class under the test

Comment: Ok, so how can the method be tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Mockito` at all to test `methodToTest()`, since no third party classes (like `Utility`, which you mock in your `ServiceTest`) are called:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

class MyTest {

    private Service service = new Service();

    @Test
    void name() {    
        Flux<String> actual = service.methodToTest();

        StepVerifier.create(actual)
                .expectNext("test")
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

More information about testing reactive streams can be found in this article: https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher

Answer (score 1):

Mockito is giving you what the problem is.

In the absence of any other evidence, it appears you are attempting to mock on a real object.

If your intent is to override and mock a particular method, you may need to create the mock on an interface matching that signature OR create a `spy` on that object.

The second part indicating `when() requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock` is what it is saying.